# Protractor. ''No element found message'' instead of ''expectationFailOutput'' text

Tags: testing, protractor

Using Protractor, I spotted that wished fail output is replaced by just absent element message. For instance:
I have:

```
await expect(await login.mainError.getText()).toBe('We do not recognize that email.', `Actual login error message: ${blabla }does not match expected: 'TEST CORRECT'`)
```

instead of seeing this one when test failing:

```
ERROR: Actual login error message: ${blabla }does not match expected: 'TEST CORRECT'
```

I primitively see

```
Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .common-form-error)
```

Do I do something wrong or expectationOutPut is not relevant?
Thanks

Comment: What testing framework do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Your element login.mainError is not being found. the .getText() promise has to resolve before the code can move onto the expect statement. The error message you are getting is a result of the .getText() statement failing.